# Can I generate a random matrix with a given condition number using the infinite norm?

Tags: matrices, matrix-norms, condition-number

I'm trying to generate random matrices that have a given condition number for inversion.
For that I need to have matrices for which the condition number is low (or controlled) when computed using the infinite norm.
I've found some methods used the *SVD* method to generate matrices with specific condition numbers using the  2-norm, but I have yet to find a method that generates matrices with controlled infinite norm based condition number.
Thanks!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: A closely related question and answer can be found here https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2442310/307944
The answer presented below is however more specific and constructive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Choose any matrix $E \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times m}$ and scale the rows such that $\|E\|_\infty  = \epsilon < 1$. Consider the matrix $$A=I-E.$$ where $I$ is the identity matrix of dimension $m$. Then $A$ is nonsingular and $$A^{-1} = \sum_{j=0}^\infty E^j.$$ This is known as the Neumann series. By the triangular inequality we have $$\|A\|_\infty \leq 1 + \|E\|_\infty$$ and $$\|A^{-1}\|_\infty \leq \sum_{j=0}^\infty \|E\|_\infty^j = \frac{1}{1 - \|E\|_\infty}.$$ It follows that $$\kappa_\infty(A) = \|A\|_\infty \|A^{-1}\|_\infty \leq \frac{1 + \epsilon}{1 - \epsilon}.$$

A complete MATLAB program that implements this strategy is given here.

```
function A=TestMatrix(m,epsilon)

% Generates a nonsingular matrix while bounding the condition number
%
% Call sequence: A = TestMatrix(m,epsilon)
%
% INPUT:
%    m        the dimension of the matrix
%    epsilon  a real number in (0,1)
%
% OUTPUT:
%    A        an m by m nonsingular matrix
%
% The infinity norm condition number of A is bounded by 
% 
%                (1+epsilon)/(1-epsilon)
% 

% Programming by Carl Christian Kjelgaard Mikkelsen
%   2021-10-22 Initial programming and testing

% Generate a random matrix with entries uniformly distributed in (0,1)
E=rand(m,m);
% Compute the sum of the absolute values of E along each row
w=abs(E)*ones(m,1);
% Scale E to ensure that the infinity norm is epsilon
E=epsilon*(diag(w)\E);
% Construct the final matrix
A=eye(m,m)-E;
```

Comment: This is extremely helpful, many thanks!

Comment: @Pyoz_ You are very welcome. Note, I changed a sign in the last line of the MATLAB function. It does not change the validity of the construction, it just matches the code directly to the reasoning.